# VirtualBox host-only networking on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: networking, virtualbox, network-manager, virtualbox-networking

I run VirtualBox 6.0.6 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and I've got two Windows XP VM's. I want to make a network connection, only between those two. I've tried to use the host-only option, but I couldn't receive a ping from the other machine.

First, I went to `Host Network Manager` (Ctrl+H), and set up 2 virtual networks, named `vboxnet0` and `vboxnet1`, with those settings:
[image: vboxnet0 settings][image: vboxnet1 settings]
I've disabled the DHCP Server option in both of them.

Next, I've changed the network settings of the first machine, to be:[image: VM1 network settings] And the second machine settings, to be:[image: VM2 network settings]

Then, inside the first Windows VM, I've set the following network settings: [image: VM1 inside network settings] And on the second Windows VM, the following settings: [image: VM2 inside network settings]

In my Ubuntu host machine, I've turned on IP forwarding and enabled packet forwarding in the firewall, with the following commands:

```
$ sudo su
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
# iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

Then, to check the connection, I've run both of these VMs and tried to send a ping from the first VM to the second VM. I managed to receive a ping from the default gateway IP, but not from the IP of the second machine, as follows:
[image: connection test]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I forgot to turn off the firewall on both of the Windows VMs.

This is how to solve the problem:

1. Go to the `Windows Security Center`. You can find the `Windows Security Center` in an obscure corner of the Windows infrastructure: Choose Start→All Programs→Accessories→System Tools→Security Center. [image: Security Center Path]
   You will get this window: [image: Security Center Window]
2. Click on `Windows Firewall` on the bottom right. Then, choose the `Off (not recommended)` option, and then click the `OK` button. [image: Turn off firewall]
3. Do the same thing for both of your VMs and you are good to go.